# What happened to plugins in PhoneGap 3.3?

Tags: cordova

What happened to plugins in PhoneGap 3.3? Are they stored in a different place now?

cordova_plugins.js doesn't update now and I don't know where the js portion of plugins are, that folder doesn't exist anymore. If I list the plugins via the command line it still shows all the installed plugins though.

cordova_plugins.js is just...

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

Comment: The config.xml gets updated but the cordova_plugins.js doesn't

Comment: I'm also struggling with this new plugin system they now use a registry and plugman to manage them. So far I haven't been able to get them working.

Comment: Is it just 3.3 (should I try 3.2 instead? I Am struggling for days now with upgrade from 2.9 to 3.3) Or are you also new in the 3.x structure? What was your previous release phonegap version?

Comment: @michel.iamit Things are workable now, after installing a new plugin I run `cordova build ios`. This builds the needed `cordova_plugins.js` but it also sets the project back to its defaults (config.xml will be reset, all your assets will be reset) after I run it i drop all my assets back in (html/js/css) and change the few flags I need in config.xml and it works. ---- I'm sure this is not the way it's suppose to work and will hopefully get fixed but I don't install plugins too much so it works for me right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After installing the plugins (as per directions) running `cordova build ios` (or the like) seem'd to generate the needed cordova_plugin.js code and move the plugins javascript files to the correct directory.

Note: This will also set the project back to its defaults (config.xml will be reset, all your assets will be reset) after I run it i drop all my assets back in (html/js/css) and change the few flags I need in config.xml and it works. I'm sure this is not the way it's suppose to work and will hopefully get fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I just found out today. I work in eclipse, and android, but using the 'cordova build' command (without platform works for me) between editting in the blue print www folder and running it in eclipse, seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Not working with Android :/ why ? and how to know what to updated in the cordova_plugins.js file

Comment: I experienced the same issue with Android, however not all of the Java src files (under android/src/org/apache/cordova) were updated for the plugins I had added. My interim remedy was to create a new Basic Phonegap app, add the plugins I need, do a build, then compare the file diff with my real project. That way I wouldn't lose my real project every time I did a build.

Comment: just to clarify. after every installation of the plugin trigger 'cordova build ios' and that solved the problem?